# error 400 when try to make ajax request with type post to function OnPostshiftDataUp

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, razor-pages, webapi

I am working with Asp.Net Core Razor Pages. I get an error when trying make ajax request to access `OnPostshiftDataUp`

```
ERROR : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () 

console.log(formdata) // serialize data

serverip=172.16.224.999&printername=Zebra2&Location=SupervisorOffice&__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8DvYZnvxyLVKi-zvp3jzTImPtgQsnvTBz4ot8mbln2lEaqGcaT_gzZ-KNNfuEBoqHYSBIdcahXL3LLuum4nfTi2oZDQj-PfodyDAVpa45rYEIb7EcRvHrMn71AyB8PMC6DrqvT8q3cCEcSlt1sYQJ-M
```

but break point not catch this function meaning not detect there are breakpoint must catch it

the main purpose from ajax request is save data after update data on bootstrap model

what I try for my code

1- function with type post on page model

```
public ActionResult OnPostshiftDataUp()
        {

            
            return Content("msg");
           
        }
```

2- ajax request to access function or action  `OnPostshiftDataUp`
ajax request i do it

```
$('#save-btn').click(function () {
                var formData = $('#edit-form').serialize();
                console.log(formData);
            
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=shiftDataUp',
                    
         
                    type: "POST",
                  
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            
                   
                    success: function (result) {
                     
                        $('#edit-modal').modal('hide');
       
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
```

bootstrap model then send ajax request when click button save

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editshelflabelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">
                @*<img src="@Url.Content("~/Img/UserProfile1.png")" alt="ImageProfile" style="width:22%;height:10%" />*@

            </h5>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editshelflabelModaldata" style="margin-left:200px;">Hi,@TempData["UserID"]</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                  <form id="edit-form" method="post">
                  @*  <input type="hidden" id="edit-id" name="ShiftId">*@
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-server">Server IP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-ip" name="serverip">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-printer">Printer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-printername" name="printername">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-locationsdata">Location Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-Location" value="save" name="Location">
                    </div>
                </form>
                @*<div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="serverIp" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">Server IP</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input id="serverIp" asp-for="User.UserName" readonly type="text" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" maxlength="30" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-btn">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**updated post**

issue still exist after apply answer below :

**error display Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()**

so what i do to solve error

**Last updated Post**
issue until now not solved can you please help me by sending full sample with bootstrap model and jQuery and html table may be i have issue on some parts please

**From code below request success done but function post `PostshiftDataUp()`
not cached or hit after click save button**

Full code sample for what I try

```
program.cs
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");   

 public class ShelfLabelPrinterSetUpModel : PageModel
    {
 [BindProperty]
        public string serverip { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string printername { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string Location { get; set; }
public IActionResult OnPostshiftDataUp(string serverip, string printername, string location)
        {
            return new JsonResult("Success");

        }
}
<div class="modal fade" id="editshelflabelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userDetailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">
               

            </h5>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editshelflabelModaldata" style="margin-left:200px;">Hi,@TempData["UserID"]</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="edit-form" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-server">Server IP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-ip" name="serverip">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-printer">Printer Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-printername" name="printername">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="edit-locationsdata">Location Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="edit-Location"  name="Location">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-btn">Save changes</button>
                </form>
              
                <a href="/"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Sign Out</a>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table id="editbootstarp">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
            <th>BranchType</th>
            <th>UserPC</th>
            <th>PrinterName</th>
            <th>ArabicConfig</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Location Name</th>
            <th>>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
        @foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">@row["AutoID"]</td>
                <td>@row["BranchType"]</td>
                <td>@row["UserPC"]</td>

                 <td>@row["PrinterName"]</td>
                <td>@row["ArabicConfig"]</td>
                <td>@row["Status"]</td>
                <td>@row["DisplayName"]</td>
                <td>
               <button class="editbt"   data.Location="@row["DisplayName"]" data.printername="@row["PrinterName"]" data.serverip="@row["UserPC"]">Edit</button>
             </td>  
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#editbootstarp tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                // Get the data from the clicked row
                var rowData = $(this).children('td').map(function () {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get();
                $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-ip').val(rowData[2]);
                $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-printername').val(rowData[3]);
                $('#editshelflabelModal #edit-Location').val(rowData[6]);
                $('#editshelflabelModal').modal('show');
            });
  $('#save-btn').click(function () {
                var formData = $('#edit-form').serialize();
                console.log(formData);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=shiftDataUp',
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    data:formData,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            });
            
    });
 });
```

image for more details
[image: image for issue still exist]

network tool browser gool chrome result also
Request URL:
https://localhost:7160/ShelfLabelPrinterSetUp?handler=shiftDataUp
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
200
Remote Address:
[::1]:7160
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: issue still exist after apply answer below

Comment: i updated original post

Comment: i make alternative way but not catch function also so what i do

Comment: thanks for support but issue until now not solved can you please help me by sending full sample with bootstrap model and jquery please

Comment: thanks for reply issue solved by below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a 400 Bad Request because you are failing the anti-request forgery check which is built into Razor Pages by default: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification

When you convert the form data to JSON, the request verification token is hidden in the request body as part of the JSON payload. Razor Pages is unable to read the token in that condition, so you need to send the request verification token in the headers:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '?handler=shiftDataUp',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "RequestVerificationToken" : $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(formData)
    ...
```

Alternatively, don't serialise the form to JSON. Send it as-is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '?handler=shiftDataUp',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#edit-form').serialize()
        ...
```

Comment: thanks for support but issue still exist and give me same error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: so what i do to solve issue please

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz The alternative is not to serialise the data to JSON. Updated the answer with an example

Comment: i try alternative way but not catch function also so what i do

Comment: if i user alternative way i will send header also  or no need and also i will send countertype : application/json or no need